# How to insert a char value enclosed in square brackets. Getting error column 'value' does not exist in the 'table'?

Tags: sql, insert

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to insert a value "['HCC111', 'HCC112']" in a redshift column but getting an error  which says column "['HCC111', 'HCC112']" does not exist in the table. Is there a workaround for this ?

Query:

```
insert into #trhcc values('COMMUNITY V22', "['HCC111', 'HCC112']",'HCC10')
```

Here is the snapshot of the query that is submitted --
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are running *as text*.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 1):

`"['HCC111', 'HCC112']"`  is not a valid way because you used doube quotes. Text must use single quotes. Your problem is that you also use single quotes in your entry text. That is easily solved by escaping your single quotes. You do that by doubling the single quote like so:

```
'[''HCC111'', ''HCC112'']'
```